# Laravel 9, push component js to parent of parent stack

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables

I've ran into a problem trying to use Laravel components together with the **@push()** directive, as the JS inside the component doesn't appear in the *layout* **@stack()**.

I have a component named **toggle.blade.php**, and it has a **push('scripts')** directive that would be used to do some component specific js for controls, as such:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button"
        class="@if ($firstActive) @isset($classesOne) {{ $classesOne }} active @endisset @else btn btn-default @endif">{{ $buttonOne }}</button>
    <button type="button"
        class="@if (!$firstActive) @isset($classesTwo) {{ $classesTwo }} active @endisset @else btn btn-default @endif">{{ $buttonTwo }}</button>
</div>

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        $(function() {
            console.log('toggle init');
        })
    </script>
@endpush
```

The component is rendered in a controller method, inside a datatable row, as such, and returned to **index.blade.php**:

```
$table->editColumn('enabled', function ($row) {
     $toggle = new Toggle('Enabled', 'Disabled', true);
     return $toggle->render()->with($toggle->data());
});
```

This is the component class that is being used, **Toggle.php**:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Toggle extends Component
{
    public $buttonOne;
    public $buttonTwo;
    public $classesOne;
    public $classesTwo;
    public $firstActive;

    public function __construct(string $buttonOne, string $buttonTwo, bool $firstActive = true, string $classesOne = "btn btn-success", string $classesTwo = "btn btn-danger")
    {
        $this->buttonOne = $buttonOne;
        $this->buttonTwo = $buttonTwo;
        $this->classesOne = $classesOne;
        $this->classesTwo = $classesTwo;
        $this->firstActive = $firstActive;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.toggle');
    }
}
```

This is how the **index.blade.php** looks, it extends **layouts.dashboard**, and the said layout extends **layouts.app** that has a **stack('scripts')**, that I'm trying to push component JS to.

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@push('styles')
    <link href="{{ mix('/css/campaigns.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
@endpush

@section('content-header')
    <x-header :breadcrumbs="$breadcrumbs">
        <x-slot name="title">
            {{ __('cruds.title') }} {{ __('cruds.campaigns.title') }}
        </x-slot>
    </x-header>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <x-container id="page-container">
        <x-card>
            <x-slot name="slot">
                <x-table id="campaign-table">
                    <th>
                        {{ __('cruds.tables.id') }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        {{ __('cruds.tables.logo') }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        {{ __('cruds.tables.title') }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        {{ __('cruds.tables.enabled') }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        {{ __('global.created_at') }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        {{ __('global.updated_at') }}
                    </th>
                </x-table>
            </x-slot>
        </x-card>
    </x-container>
@endsection

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var platformId = @json($platforms->pluck('id')->first());
            var formatId = @json($formats->pluck('id')->first());
            loadDatatable(formatId, platformId);

            $('#formats-tabs .nav-item:not(.dropdown)').on('click', function(event) {
                formatId = $(this).find('.nav-link').data('formats-tab-id');
                loadDatatable(formatId, platformId);
            });

            $('#platforms-tabs .nav-item:not(.dropdown)').on('click', function(event) {
                platformId = $(this).find('.nav-link').data('platforms-tab-id');
                loadDatatable(formatId, platformId);
            });

            function loadDatatable(formatId, platformId) {
                //If datatable exists reset it to initial state.
                if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#campaign-table')) {
                    $('#campaign-table').DataTable().clear();
                    $('#campaign-table').DataTable().destroy();
                }

                Helper.initDatatable({
                    selector: "#campaign-table",
                    ajax: {
                        url: "{{ route('dashboard.campaigns.datatable') }}",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: {
                            formatId: formatId,
                            platformId: platformId
                        }
                    },
                    deletePermission: "{{ Gate::allows('campaigns_delete') }}",
                    deleteURL: "{{ route('dashboard.campaigns.massDestroy') }}",
                    columns: [{
                            data: 'placeholder',
                            name: 'placeholder'
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'id',
                            name: 'id'
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'logo',
                            name: 'logo'
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'title',
                            name: 'title'
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'enabled',
                            name: 'enabled'
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'created_at',
                            name: 'created_at',
                            visible: false
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'updated_at',
                            name: 'updated_at',
                            visible: false
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'actions',
                            name: "{{ __('global.actions') }}"
                        }
                    ],
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    @stack('page-js')
@endpush
```

This is **layouts.dashboard**:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', __('panel.site_title'))

@push('styles')
    <link href="{{ mix('/css/dashboard.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
@endpush

@section('body-classes', 'sidebar-mini ')
@section('classes', 'wrapper')

@section('app')
    @include('dashboard._header')
    @include('dashboard._sidebar')

    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                @yield('content-header')
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                @yield('content')
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    @include('dashboard._footer')
@endsection

@prepend('scripts')
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
@endprepend
```

And finally, the **layout.app** page, that has the **stack('scripts')** itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"> -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    @stack('meta')
    <title>
        @yield('title')
    </title>
    @stack('styles')
</head>

<body class="@yield('body-classes')">
    <div id="app" class="@yield('classes')">
        @yield('app')
    </div>
    @stack('modals')
    @stack('scripts')
</body>

</html>
```

The goal is for when the datatable is rendered for the js of the component to get pushed into the **layout.app @stack('scripts')**.

Is that a possible? Since the **index.blade.php** already pushes scripts to the stack, and that appears fine, yet the component js doesn't.

EDIT: The push to **stack('scripts')** doesn't work only when returning the Toggle render from the datatable, works when put in index.blade.php as a <x-toggle *params*>